# Small code conversion from TOS to Pine script Version 5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I'm new to pine script. I am trying to convert a code from Thinkscript to Pine version 5 and running into a problem. Here is the code from TOS:

```
def NetChgAvg = MovingAverage(averageType, X - X[1], Length);
def TotChgAvg = MovingAverage(averageType, AbsValue(X - X[1]), Length);
def ChgRatio = if FTotChgAvg != 0 then NetChgAvg / TotChgAvg else 0;
```

The first two lines are not the problem. The error is the third line:

```
FNetChgAvg = ta.ema(X - X[1], Length)
FTotChgAvg = ta.ema(math.abs(X - X[1]), Length)
FChgRatio = if (FTotChgAvg != 0) (FNetChgAvg / FTotChgAvg) 0
```

Error ---> Syntax error at input 'FNetChgAvg' pointing to the third line ratio.

I looked over the documentation and some examples but the problem continues.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
FNetChgAvg = ta.ema(X - X[1], Length)
FTotChgAvg = ta.ema(math.abs(X - X[1]), Length)
FChgRatio = 0
if FTotChgAvg != 0
    FChgRatio := FNetChgAvg / FTotChgAvg
else
    FChgRatio := 0
```

Comment: I managed to get it work. Thanks!